# Sorting ArrayList<> based on Lattitude and Longitude in Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, shortest-path

I Have a requirement that has ArrayList that contains Latitude and Longitude (randomly).Is there any way so that I can get this list in a optimized way. Google Map optimization map I am aware of that but I need the list optimized / sorted based on latlong.

Please Let me know if you have any solution

Comment: share the array list before and after sorting. are you using **java** or **javascript**? Define *optimized way*

Comment: It is for Android(Java).I want the arraylist in such a way that it sould be in ascending order.So the driver could pick the pickup one by one in a shortest route.

Comment: Post the data  - show the array before/after sorting